# number of ways to get n pairs of sticks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was practicing problems from [CMU HW](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/weikang/math325/SolHW3.pdf). In problem 3: Suppose that each of n sticks is broken into one long and one short part. The 2n parts are then
shuffled and arranged into n pairs from which new sticks are formed
It says
The total number of ways to get n pairs is $\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n)n!}$
Can someone please explain the denominator part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** if you order everything you will get your numerator..so you start by taking pairs in that order, at the end you will end up with an **ordered** set of pairs and each pair is going to have an order on it.

Comment: I understand that there will be 2n pieces now and that gives (2n)! . I dont understand the rest of it

Comment: So, in how many ways can you order the pairs if you have $n$ of them?
And inside the pairs you have $2$ elements..but there are $n$ pairs.

Comment: Okay. I have 2n pieces of sticks which gives (2n)!. And n pairs of them can be arranged in n! ways and in each pair we have 2 arrangements for n pairs.
So should it not be (2n)! * (2^n) * n! ?

Comment: No, but 0k see it this way. Call $D$ to your number, then you know that if you have your pairs **without any order** and then you order the pairs $n!$ and you order each pair $2^n$ then you will get $D *n!*2^n$ but that is the same as just order everything $2n!$.

Comment: Ya. That's true. But I still don't understand it clearly as to why it goes to denominator

Comment: Because is like an equivalent relationship between unordered pairs and each class(the classes are exactly what you are counting) has the same number of elements in it (i.e., $n!2^n$). So, in the end, you are dividing the whole ordered set of sticks on those equivalent classes.